# How to make bootstrap thumbnails same size, even after resizing the window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and I have a few thumbnails in a div that I want to dynamically resize to be an equal height. I found two scripts to do this on stackoverflow:

**Option 1** ([bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/morganhancock/SLG3rtLxlB))

```
    function equalHeight(group) {    
    var tallest = 0;    
    group.each(function() {       
        var thisHeight = $(this).height();       
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {          
            tallest = thisHeight;       
        }    
    });    
    group.each(function() { $(this).height(tallest); });
 } 

  $(document).ready(function() {   
    equalHeight($(".equalize")); 
  });
```

**Option 2** ([bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/morganhancock/d1Ol8qJ4TK))

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var maxHeight = 0;          
    $(".equalize").each(function(){
      if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
    });         
    $(".equalize").height(maxHeight);
  });
```

But neither totally solves my problem. If you resize the window (past a breakpoint so the column width containing the thumbnail changes), the content spills out of the thumbnails. You can test this in my bootply examples.

I think I need to add an EventHandler like `window.onresize` or something, but I haven't been able to get it to work. Where and how would I add that to the javascript file? I'm really really new to JS, so I'd really appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 1):

I decided to use Flexbox to fix this. The javascript suggestions didn't work because the original function wrote the height for the objects and wouldn't overwrite that height on resize (I think because after the initial load, the object then had a set height).

Here's the Flexbox code that solved the issue ([codepen demo](http://codepen.io/mhancock/pen/rLEqkj))

**HTML**

```
<div class="row equalize-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 equalize">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        ...
        </div>
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.equalize-row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.equalize {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Match height JS will do what you need. All you do is add the reference https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.0/jquery.matchHeight-min.js" and this little code snippet:

```
$(function() {
    $('.equalize').matchHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your first example, simply add a resize handler like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    equalHeight($(".equalize")); 

    $(window).resize(function() {
        equalHeight($(".equalize"));
    });
 });
```

That should do the trick. I'm not at my computer so I can't test it. Let me know how it works.